# Error: Current Displayable is an Alert

Tags: exception, java-me

I get the following error:

```
Illegal Argument java/lang/IllegalArgumentException Current Displayable is an Alert
```

I'm not sure what is means and why this exception is fired.

Comment: How can I prevent this Error from happening?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer on the [nokia forum](http://www.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=194781#2)!
It is an exception thrown when calling `Display.setCurrent()` with an Alert as the argument, while an Alert is already displayed.